# Interesting vs fascinating

Tags: differences

When I said "fascinating" in basic conversation, my English teacher said interesting in response.
I'd like to catch the specific difference between them.

Comment: The difference is actually somewhat more nuanced than the answer posted below might suggest. For a detailed discussion of the difference between _interesting_ and _fascinating_ in meaning and orientation, see my answer to the EL&U Meta question [Are "commonly available" reference dictionaries too simplistic to answer questions on this site?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13211/are-commonly-available-reference-dictionaries-too-simplistic-to-answer-questio)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in intensity: *fascinating* means *extremely interesting*.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fascinating

Comment: An earlier close-vote set comment read 'This question is too basic; it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information.' It was probably downtoned to be kinder to newcomers, but still applies. And to quote @Rathony, 'We do not encourage an answer to an off-topic question. If you want to help the Original Poster, please post it as a comment'

Comment: Moreover, closed questions are only deleted from the system when the answer(s) have no score. As such your answer might be target of strategic down voting if does get up voted.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't care.

Comment: @Helmar I don't care. If you two have problems with the question, take it up with the OP and stop badgering people who are only trying to help. I don't need anyone's permission to answer a question - and the question is still not closed now, not to mention when I answered it.

Comment: But I _do_ care. You could have helped the OP by giving this as a comment instead of an answer, and helped the people who do care about keeping 'please look this up for me' questions off ELU, to preserve its credibility as a site for linguists, at the same time. _Who_ are you trying to help? There are plenty of other websites for very basic questions and / or those not accompanied by a reasonable amount of research.

Comment: I don't need your lecturing.